# How to use swiftyjson to parse json data to foundation object and loop through data

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

So I'm trying to get his raw json data and use it to ultimately be viewed in a table(so one table cell would be -->     Emirates - $1588.77)

Problem: Having trouble parsing the JSON data.. alamofire apparently does it automatically? but im completely confused with the data types. I keep getting weird errors like 'doesnt have a member named subscript" (I've also got swiftyjson installed but aa non-swiftyjson solution should work as well.

Code:

```
    request(qpxRequest).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
        if response != nil {
           //println(response!)
        }
        if json != nil {


          // 1. parse the JSON data into a Foundation object
         // 2. Grab the data from the foundation object (so its can be looped though      in a table)
```

}

---

```
{
trips =     {
    data =         {
        carrier =             (
                            {
                name = "Cathay Pacific Airways Ltd.";
            },
                            {
                name = Emirates;
            },
                            {
                name = "Ethiopian Airlines Enterprise";
            },
                            {
                name = "Qantas Airways Ltd.";
            },
                            {
                name = "South African Airways";
            }
        );
    };
    tripOption =         (
                    {
            saleTotal = "AUD1537.22";
        },
                    {
            saleTotal = "AUD1588.77";
        },
                    {
            saleTotal = "AUD1857.42";
        },
                    {
            saleTotal = "AUD1857.42";
        },
                    {
            saleTotal = "AUD1922.42";
        }
    );
};
```

}

---

--------  Edit.

---

Using this model.

```
class FlightDataModel {
    var carrier: String
    var price: String

    init(carrier: String?, price: String?) {
        self.carrier = carrier! 
        self.price = price!
    }
}
```

How woudl I use your solution to add it to an array of FlightDataModel class

This my my attempt..

```
var arrayOfFlights : [FlightDataModel] = [FlightDataModel]()



 if let tripOptions = trips["tripOption"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                        for (index, tripOption) in enumerate(tripOptions) {
                            //println("\(index): " + (tripOption["saleTotal"]! as String))

                            self.arrayOfFlights[index].carrier = tripOption["saleTotal"]! as String


                            println("\(self.arrayOfFlights[index].carrier)")
                        }
```

Comment: Can you put the line which gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire can do it, but *you* have to dig into your JSON structure. :)

Like this, using Alamofire's `responseJSON` method:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, YOUR_URL, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL).responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros) { (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
        if let myJSON = json as? [String:AnyObject] {
            if let trips = myJSON["trips"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                if let data = trips["data"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                    if let carriers = data["carrier"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        for (index, carrierName) in enumerate(carriers) {
                            println("\(index): " + carrierName["name"]!)
                        }
                    }
                }
                if let tripOptions = trips["tripOption"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                    for (index, tripOption) in enumerate(tripOptions) {
                        println("\(index): " + (tripOption["saleTotal"]! as! String))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
0: Cathay Pacific Airways Ltd.
1: Emirates
...
0: AUD1537.22
1: AUD1588.77
...
```

It's a bit easier with SwiftyJSON indeed. And for diversity's sake, we'll use Alamofire's `responseString` method this time:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, YOUR_URL, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL).responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, completionHandler: {(request: NSURLRequest, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, responseBody: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let dataFromString = responseBody!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
            let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
            let carriers = json["trips"]["data"]["carrier"].array
            for (index, carrier) in enumerate(carriers!) {
                println("\(index):" + carrier["name"].string!)
            }
            let tripOption = json["trips"]["tripOption"].array
            for (index, option) in enumerate(tripOption!) {
                println("\(index):" + option["saleTotal"].string!)
            }
        }

    })
```

Output:

```
0: Cathay Pacific Airways Ltd.
1: Emirates
...
0: AUD1537.22
1: AUD1588.77
...
```

*Note: I've used `enumerate` as an example for how getting the index of the content at the same time you get the content.*

Comment: That worked! hallelujah. Could you have a look at my edit up above? im trying to put the data togethor into an array of  flightdatamodel class.  Please let me knwo what you think.  Thanks Eric

Comment: I'm asking because the data isnt showing up in the console.

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with how you try to create your object on the line `self.arrayOfFlights[index].carrier = ...` But I'm afraid it's an entire other topic than this question. My suggestion: either you create another question about this, or we can have a *quick* discussion in the chat. :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to use the chat. Come to this url: https://tlk.io/swift

Comment: I dont have 20 reputation. It wont allow me to talk.   Come here:   tlk.io/swift

Comment: let myFlight = FlightDataModel(carrier: carrierName["name"] as String)              Has the error "missing argument for parameter 'price' in call"

Comment: Yes, look at how your model is created: `var price: String` is not an Optional, so it is mandatory to initialize it when creating the object (even if you did put optionals in the init method call, it doesn't change the actual type of the variable, and you force unwrap in the init anyway...). Either you create the object by initializing the two parameters (price + carrier) or you make `price` an Optional by adding `?` like this:  `var price: String?` and you don't force unwrap in the init.

Comment: At this point, I seriously suggest you leave this post alone and prepare another question (this post is about parsing and it's solved, now you want to create a custom object with your data and that's a different problem/topic), where you give the context of what you're doing, how you're doing it and where the error is. Here in the comments you won't get so much help now... :)